# How to make a backgroundtask run in-process

Tags: uwp, background-task

I have Cordova based JS UWP app. It is a startup project. It is also using C++ WINRT component. I want the background task (written in C++) to communicate with the main APP.

If the Startup app is C++/C# , we can specify in the app manifest file

```
<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BGTASK.BackGroundTaskHandler" Executable="MainApp.exe">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="systemEvent" />
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
```

But if the main app is JS app, on specifying Executable="MainApp.exe" it throws an error. Can anybody tell how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Executable is not required, you can omit it and is should work.